# copying a key frame from file to file

Tags: animation

i'm just starting to use blender. I made a rookie mistake and deleted an actor from a file. is there a way to copy the beginning or end key frame from one file to another?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the original somewhere, you can copy it with CTRL+C and then paste it into another Blender instance with CTRL-V.

If you lost the original blend file, you can click on File > Recover Auto Save.

Comment: I don't have a file with the movement I need. But I do have the file before and the file after. I want to copy the last keyframe from one and the first of the other. I understand I would need to fill in the missing movements. I just want them to play seamlessly.